# what does "public static final long USER_ACCOUNT = 32L" means? what suffix L means in long variable?

Tags: java, literals

I found code snippet here

```
public static final long USER_ACCOUNT = 32L;
```

what it means `32L` here? does it means just a `long` variable having numeric value `32` or it means long will take 32 bit of values?

and what if i don't provide latter `L` end of digit `32`?

Comment: this means that USER_ACCOUNT is a constant and would be accessible to every other class and can't be changed. 32L shows the variable is a long value. It represent the value not the 32 bits

Comment: The `final` modifier is important. `public static final` makes the primitive (or String) a *compile-time-constant* and passes the values of that field in the byte-code itself. You will understand the exact difference if you look at the byte code using `javap -v classname`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An "L" suffix is required in writing a long literal in Java.  (You could use a lower case "l" but that is very easily misread as a one.)  Long constants are stored as 64-bit two's-complement values.  Without the "L" it would be an int literal; but in this case it would give the same result.

Here is a link [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html] to a short page in the Oracle Java documentation that expands on this post.  The first portion of the page talks about Java data types and how much memory each type occupies, and the next portion of the page talks about how to write Java literals for each of the different data types.

Comment: thnank you for your explaination

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a long constant, the **L** (Capital L) is just a suffix.

The Java spec allows both upper and lower case suffixes, but the upper case version for longs is preferred, as the upper case L is less easy to confuse with a numeral 1 than the lower case l.

You can get more info about Java specifications [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10).

Comment: what if i don't provide latter L? does it affect?

Comment: @GirdharSinghRathore not in this case.  You need to specify the `L` suffix explicitly if the constant is too big to fit in an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's make this clear:

- In Java, `32` is an integal constant of type `int`.
- `32L` is an integal constant of type `long`.

Why is it important to distinguish these two types? Here are the rules:

- An `int` constant must not exceed the range of `int`, which is from -2147483648 to 2147483647 inclusive. Values outside this range trigger a compile error, for example `4123456789`.
- A `long` constant must not exceed the range of `long`, which is a much larger range.
- When a `long` constant is assigned to a `long` variable, it is simple and nothing special happens. For example: `long val = 32L;`
- When an `int` constant is assigned to a `long` variable, the `int` value is converted to a `long` value by the Java integer conversion rules - which means it is signed-extended from 32 bits to 64 bits. In this case, `(long)32` is exactly the same as `32L`, so `long val = 32;` does the same thing.
- However, some cases are deceptive: The `int` constant `0xFFFFFFFF` is **unequal** to the `long` constant `0xFFFFFFFFL`. This is because converting `0xFFFFFFFF` to `long` gives `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFL` due to sign extension.

Comment: *32L is an integer constant of type long.*?